# Apache POI Excel text formatting through XSSFRichTexString and Jsoup

Tags: java, apache-poi, jsoup, xssf, poi-hssf

I was getting the html data from database. 
Below is the example :

```
    <ul>
    <li> <strong>Iam Bold </strong> <u><span style="color:Red">Iam Red Colored and   Underlined</span> </u> </li>
    <li> Just a Normal Text </li>
     <li> Iam <b> Bold </b> <i><span style="color:Green"> and italic with colored </span></i> <u> and underlined </u> </li>
    </ul>
```

Now the same formatting is to be there in my excel output.
Please see the below image for excel output.

[image]

I know that by using Jsoup , you can parse the above html and by using XSSFRichTextString , you can show the richtext in xssfcell. Also by using bullet character i can get the bullet icon.

But i need the complete text as it was in the output.
But Iam not getting any idea on how exactly to do that to get the exact output.

How to do that by using XSSFRichTextString?
Please help me on this

Comment: In short, Say, the value that I need to set in some cell in the excel could be something like
<i>italics </i>plain <b> <i> boldItalics</i></b><b> allThree</b><b><i><u> plain</u></i></b>

Whatever is there inside 
      <i> italic text</i> should be set as italics
      <b>bold text </b> should be set as bold
      <u>underlined text </u> should be set as underline

Comment: Jsoup may not be of much help here. You'll have to write your own parser to  interpret the markup and create the necessary objects. That will be tricky though. Since the fonts are applied to indexes you will have to play a lot around tag positions. Also style tag as in `<span style="color:Red">` will make it even more complex.

Comment: Okie.. leaving span style, any help regarding other tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment this would be tricky implmentation. You need to create a parser to intrepret the html markup and apply those as fonts. The below program can be used as a starter for the parser. It uses [jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) parser for parsing html and has limited font support. However It handles the html you have given (it might be able to implmented this in a lot better way). Also you can extend this for additional font support like strike through, font size etc. You can google for various font implmentations. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import net.htmlparser.jericho.Element;
import net.htmlparser.jericho.Source;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class HtmlToExcel {

    private static final int START_TAG = 0;
    private static final int END_TAG = 1;
    private static final char BULLET_CHARACTER = '\u2022';
    private static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<ul>"
                + "<li><em><strong>Bold Non-Colored + <span style=\"color: #FF0000\">Bolded and Colored Text</span></strong> </em> + Non font trailing<br/></li>"
                + "<li>No Styling...Just a Text</li>"
                + "<li><u><b>Bolded </b> and <i>Italic </i> and Underlined Text</u></li>"
                + "<li><u>Underline Started and <span style=\"color: #00FF00\">Only Colored Text</span> Underline Ended</u></li>"
                + "</ul>";

        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Html Text");

        Source source = new Source(html);
        int cellNo = 0;
        for (Element ul : source.getAllElements("ul")) {
            List<RichTextDetails> cellValues = new ArrayList<HtmlToExcel.RichTextDetails>();
            for (Element li : ul.getAllElements("li")) {
                cellValues.add(createCellValue(li.toString(), workBook));
            }
            createCell(cellValues, workBook, sheet, cellNo++);
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
            workBook.write(out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static void createCell(List<RichTextDetails> cellValues,
            HSSFWorkbook workBook, HSSFSheet sheet, int cellNo) {
        HSSFRichTextString cellValue = mergeTextDetails(cellValues);
        HSSFCellStyle wrapStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
        wrapStyle.setWrapText(true);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(cellNo);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
    }

    private static HSSFRichTextString mergeTextDetails(
            List<RichTextDetails> cellValues) {
        StringBuilder textBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        Map<Integer, HSSFFont> mergedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, HSSFFont>();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        for(RichTextDetails richTextDetail : cellValues){
            textBuffer.append(BULLET_CHARACTER + " ");
            currentIndex = textBuffer.length();
            for (Entry<Integer, HSSFFont> entry : richTextDetail.getFontMap().entrySet()) {
            mergedMap.put(entry.getKey() + currentIndex, entry.getValue());
        }
            textBuffer.append(richTextDetail.getRichText()).append(NEW_LINE);
        }

        HSSFRichTextString richText = new HSSFRichTextString(textBuffer.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < textBuffer.length(); i++) {
        HSSFFont currentFont = mergedMap.get(i);
        if (currentFont != null) {
        richText.applyFont(i, i + 1, currentFont);
        }
    }
        return richText;
    }

    private static RichTextDetails createCellValue(String html, HSSFWorkbook workBook) {
        Source source = new Source(html);
        Map<String, TagInfo> tagMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, HtmlToExcel.TagInfo>();
        for (Element e : source.getChildElements()) {
            getInfo(e, tagMap);
        }

        String patternString = "(" + StringUtils.join(tagMap.keySet(), "|") + ")";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

        StringBuffer textBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        List<RichTextInfo> textInfos = new ArrayList<HtmlToExcel.RichTextInfo>();
        Stack<RichTextInfo> richTextBuffer = new Stack<HtmlToExcel.RichTextInfo>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(textBuffer, "");
            TagInfo currentTag = tagMap.get(matcher.group(1));
            if (START_TAG == currentTag.getTagType()) {
                richTextBuffer.push(getRichTextInfo(currentTag, textBuffer.length(), workBook));
            } else {
                if (!richTextBuffer.isEmpty()) {
                    RichTextInfo info = richTextBuffer.pop();
                    if (info != null) {
                        info.setEndIndex(textBuffer.length());
                        textInfos.add(info);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(textBuffer);
        Map<Integer, HSSFFont> fontMap = buildFontMap(textInfos, workBook);

        return new RichTextDetails(textBuffer.toString(), fontMap);
    }

    private static Map<Integer, HSSFFont> buildFontMap(
            List<RichTextInfo> textInfos, HSSFWorkbook workBook) {
        Map<Integer, HSSFFont> fontMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, HSSFFont>();

        for (RichTextInfo richTextInfo : textInfos) {
            if (richTextInfo.isValid()) {
                for (int i = richTextInfo.getStartIndex(); i < richTextInfo.getEndIndex(); i++) {
                    fontMap.put(i, mergeFont(fontMap.get(i), richTextInfo.getFontStyle(), richTextInfo.getFontValue(), workBook));
                }
            }
        }

        return fontMap;
    }

    private static HSSFFont mergeFont(HSSFFont font, STYLES fontStyle,
            String fontValue, HSSFWorkbook workBook) {
        if (font == null) {
            font = workBook.createFont();
        }

        switch (fontStyle) {
            case BOLD:
            case EM:
            case STRONG:
                font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                break;
            case UNDERLINE:
                font.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
                break;
            case ITALLICS:
                font.setItalic(true);
                break;
            case COLOR:
                if (!isEmpty(fontValue)) {
                    HSSFPalette palette = workBook.getCustomPalette();
                    HSSFColor myColor = palette.findSimilarColor(
                            Integer.valueOf(fontValue.substring(2, 4), 16),
                            Integer.valueOf(fontValue.substring(4, 6), 16),
                            Integer.valueOf(fontValue.substring(6, 8), 16));
                    font.setColor(myColor.getIndex());
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return font;
    }

    private static RichTextInfo getRichTextInfo(TagInfo currentTag,
            int startIndex, HSSFWorkbook workBook) {
        RichTextInfo info = null;
        switch (STYLES.fromValue(currentTag.getTagName())) {
            case SPAN:
                if (!isEmpty(currentTag.getStyle())) {
                    for (String style : currentTag.getStyle().split(";")) {
                        String[] styleDetails = style.split(":");
                        if (styleDetails != null && styleDetails.length > 1) {
                            if ("COLOR".equalsIgnoreCase(styleDetails[0].trim())) {
                                info = new RichTextInfo(startIndex, -1, STYLES.COLOR, styleDetails[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                info = new RichTextInfo(startIndex, -1, STYLES.fromValue(currentTag.getTagName()));
                break;
        }
        return info;
    }

    private static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
        return (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0);
    }

    private static void getInfo(Element e, Map<String, HtmlToExcel.TagInfo> tagMap) {
        tagMap.put(e.getStartTag().toString(), new TagInfo(e.getStartTag().getName(), e.getAttributeValue("style"), START_TAG));
        if (e.getChildElements().size() > 0) {
            List<Element> children = e.getChildElements();
            for (Element child : children){
                getInfo(child, tagMap);
            }
        }
        if (e.getEndTag() != null) {
            tagMap.put(e.getEndTag().toString(), new TagInfo(e.getEndTag().getName(), END_TAG));
        } else {
            // Handling self closing tags
            tagMap.put(e.getStartTag().toString(), new TagInfo(e.getStartTag().getName(), END_TAG));
        }
    }

    static class RichTextInfo {
        private int startIndex;
        private int endIndex;
        private STYLES fontStyle;
        private String fontValue;

        public RichTextInfo(int startIndex, int endIndex, STYLES fontStyle) {
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
        }

        public RichTextInfo(int startIndex, int endIndex, STYLES fontStyle,
                String fontValue) {
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
            this.fontValue = fontValue;
        }

        public int getStartIndex() {
            return startIndex;
        }

        public void setStartIndex(int startIndex) {
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
        }

        public int getEndIndex() {
            return endIndex;
        }

        public void setEndIndex(int endIndex) {
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
        }

        public STYLES getFontStyle() {
            return fontStyle;
        }

        public void setFontStyle(STYLES fontStyle) {
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
        }

        public String getFontValue() {
            return fontValue;
        }

        public void setFontValue(String fontValue) {
            this.fontValue = fontValue;
        }

        public boolean isValid() {
            return (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1 && endIndex >= startIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RichTextInfo [startIndex=" + startIndex + ", endIndex="
                    + endIndex + ", fontStyle=" + fontStyle + ", fontValue="
                    + fontValue + "]";
        }
    }

    static class RichTextDetails {
        private String richText;
        private Map<Integer, HSSFFont> fontMap;

        public RichTextDetails(String richText,
                Map<Integer, HSSFFont> fontMap) {
            this.richText = richText;
            this.fontMap = fontMap;
        }

        public String getRichText() {
            return richText;
        }
        public void setRichText(String richText) {
            this.richText = richText;
        }
        public Map<Integer, HSSFFont> getFontMap() {
            return fontMap;
        }
        public void setFontMap(Map<Integer, HSSFFont> fontMap) {
            this.fontMap = fontMap;
        }
    }

    static class TagInfo {
        private String tagName;
        private String style;
        private int tagType;

        public TagInfo(String tagName, String style, int tagType) {
            this.tagName = tagName;
            this.style = style;
            this.tagType = tagType;
        }

        public TagInfo(String tagName, int tagType) {
            this.tagName = tagName;
            this.tagType = tagType;
        }

        public String getTagName() {
            return tagName;
        }

        public void setTagName(String tagName) {
            this.tagName = tagName;
        }

        public int getTagType() {
            return tagType;
        }

        public void setTagType(int tagType) {
            this.tagType = tagType;
        }

        public String getStyle() {
            return style;
        }

        public void setStyle(String style) {
            this.style = style;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TagInfo [tagName=" + tagName + ", style=" + style
                    + ", tagType=" + tagType + "]";
        }
    }

    enum STYLES {
        BOLD("b"), 
        EM("em"), 
        STRONG("strong"), 
        COLOR("color"), 
        UNDERLINE("u"), 
        SPAN("span"), 
        ITALLICS("i"), 
        UNKNOWN("unknown");

        private String type;

        private STYLES(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public static STYLES fromValue(String type) {
            for (STYLES style : values()) {
                if (style.type.equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return style;
                }
            }
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all a BIG Thanks for spending time and provinding a answer. I ran the above program, it gives the exact output but without bullet items. I just want to know whether there is a approach like - if we pass the html markup tag to excel so that it renders formatted ouput. I have gone through this links. but didnt understand what exactly going on.

Comment: Also can we do the above same formatted ouput by using aspose or itext jars in excel. so that reducing our own parsing logic.

Comment: I need a one more help from you,,, if no api or passing html markup to excel doesn;t work. I just want to update the answer with bullet points and only bold, italic and underline. No color formatting required... thanks a lot

Comment: To remove color formatting you could avoid the color `case` statement in `mergeFont()` method. I've updated the answer to give a bulleted output. Hope this helps.

Comment: @SyamS: Thanks a lot Syam for this. It really helped me to startup on my requirement. Could you please help me in converting the below html also to Excel:    "<p><strong>The <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><em>client</em> <span style=\"text-decoration: line-through;\"><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"><em>has</em></span></span></span> </strong>not <strong><em>been</em> in <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">bankruptcy</span> <span style=\"text-decoration: line-through;\">since <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"><em>1996</em></span></span>.</strong></p>

Comment: I added another loop for "P" tag and now it is working, but I am not getting strikeout text. I know we have to add in STYLES and add the same in if condition after COLOR. but I am not getting what should be the value when add strikeout in enum. Also I am trying to create html to excel woth both P and OL and UL tag. Could you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.