# interpreting html tags to while storing data in excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

I have a `List<String []> dataToExport` to store in excel file.
some of the element of `dataToExport` may contain data in the form
    **`<b><font color=grey>valueInCell</font></b>`**
My function Block to store data is

```
 public static void exportExcel(List<String[]> dataToExport,String filename){
    try {

        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
        String[] line;
        int r = 0;
        int k=0;
        while (k< dataToExport.size()) {
            line =dataToExport.get(k);
            Row row = sheet.createRow((short) r++);

            for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
                row.createCell(i)
                   .setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(line[i]));
            k++;
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How can I store only  **`valueInCell`** after interpreting html tags.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

used jericho html parser to interpret html tags.
Also you can refer [Apache POI Excel text formatting through XSSFRichTexString and Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613916/apache-poi-excel-text-formatting-through-xssfrichtexstring-and-jsoup)